# Discord Link Embed with GitHub Pages

Tags: html, discord, embed, github-pages

I'm trying to insert embed in my website hosted on GitHub Pages, but idk how I put it to show an embed when the website link is sent to a Discord channel, is it possible, if yes, how I can do it? exist a code for that? it can be configured on the GitHub Pages Tab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes there is a way to do it specificly for discord, it's pretty simple actually!

```
<meta property="og:type" content="website">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="NAME_HERE">
<meta property="og:description" content="DESC_HERE">
<meta property="og:footer" content="FOOTER_HERE">
<meta name="theme-color" content="COLOR_HERE">
  
<link type="application/json+oembed" href="embed.json">
```

you use it as a normal embed so if you wanna add an image to it you just add

```
<meta property="og:image" content="IMAGE_LINK_HERE">
```

you might see I require a json file too and you can create one if you want and define things such as `provider_url`. You can have your json file like this for example

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "author_name": "",
    "author_url": "",
    "provider_name": "",
    "provider_url": ""
}
```